# What is the difference between Accounts in Sales and Marketing in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am newbie in sugarcrm. I really get confused in the admin panel.
What is really the difference between the subpanels option in the panels.
I found it same in each panel.

Like same `Account` option in the `Sales`, `Marketing`, `Support`, `Activities` and `All`

So whats the use of providing the option in each panel, as in all the panels `Account` link goes to the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing are grouping of subpanels that are pre-defined and "optimized" for different roles in the systems. For example, a Sales Person would want to see an Account's Opportunities and History subpanels, whereas a Support Person might want to focus on Cases, Bugs and History.

Realistically, most folks can use All, which is an ever-present grouping that shows all available subpanels.

Comment: So we can hide or show the panels according to the roles define in the system. But option on each panels do the same job. eg. `Accounts` in each panel do the same job.